# Navbar that appear first

Tags: javascript, scroll, navbar

I am a newbie in coding (and english too) and I have a problem on my website.
While it is loading, the navbar appear quickly first and I don't want it. 
I would like it appear only when I'm scrolling.

Here is my website : [gaelhillion.com](http://gaelhillion.com)

Could you help me to fix it ?

Comment: Share some code, please. Here's some good docs to read - http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask - to make sure you're asking good, well-documented, well-received questions on Stack Overflow. And welcome to the community! :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The quickly appearing of the navigation bar can be fixed by adding a `display:none` to your `style.css`:

```
section#top-nav {
    display : none;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You must mean when the window is narrow, because on a big screen it acts like you want.

I'm giving you a JS-only answer because if the user is browsing with JavaScript off, you want your menu to appear. So I'm not setting the display:none in CSS.

I tested this out, and it works like you want! However you may want to further wrap the topNav.css call in a check against [window.matchMedia](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/matchMedia) so it only works on breakpoints you specify.

This script depends on jQuery, so include it after jQuery has been loaded.

JavaScript:

```
;(function ($) {
  $(function () {
    var topNav = $("#top-nav-panel").css("display", "none")

    $(window).scroll(function () {
      topNav.css("display", window.scrollY ? "block" : "none")
    })
  })
})(jQuery)
```

If it's not behaving as expected on certain touchscreen devices, you may have to listen for an event other than "scroll". [Here's a blog post about how to get things working just right.](https://www.tjvantoll.com/2012/08/19/onscroll-event-issues-on-mobile-browsers/)

Comment: Ethan how does it excatly work ?
Where do I have to put this code ? When I put it in my JS it doesn't work yet.
But the display none in my css works.